# Collation of multiple XMLs into a single XML using SSIS or SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, ssis

I have a table with the below structure.

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ColA] int,[ColB] xml)

Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (123,'<XMLData><ID>1</ID></XMLData>')
,(456,'<XMLData><ID>2</ID></XMLData>')
,(333,'<XMLData><ID>3</ID></XMLData>')
```

The XMLs are of same structure. 
Now i need to concatenate all the XMLs in ColumnB into a single XML using either SSIS or SQL. The expected result should be

```
<XMLData>
   <ID>1</ID>
   <ID>2</ID>
   <ID>3</ID>
</XMLData>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ColA] int,[ColB] xml)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (123,'<XMLData><ID>1</ID></XMLData>')
,(456,'<XMLData><ID>2</ID></XMLData>')
,(333,'<XMLData><ID>3</ID></XMLData>')

Select [*] = [ColB].query('XMLData/*') 
 From @YourTable A
 For  XML Path(''), ROOT('XMLData')
```

**Returns**

```
<XMLData>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <ID>3</ID>
</XMLData>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reponse John. The output I am expecting is 
<XMLData>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <ID>3</ID>
</XMLData>

Also, looking for an automated solution (with SSIS), if possible. Tried with XMLTask, but couldn't do much.

Comment: Yes, I got that. It's just that I want the <XMLData> to appear at the start and </XMLData> at the end rather than appearing for each ID.

Comment: @Rmani Perhaps edit your question and provide a better sample and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table name is TBL with below data model:

---

```
COLUMN_A |  COLUMN_B
  123    |    XML1
  456    |    XML2
  333    |    XML3
```

---

Use below for SQL Server

```
SELECT COLUMN_1, STRING_AGG(COLUMN_B, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_B) AS CONCATENATED_XML
FROM TBL GROUP BY COLUMN_1;
```

Use below query for Oracle

```
SELECT COLUMN_1, LISTAGG(COLUMN_B, ‘’) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_B) AS CONCATENATED_XML FROM TBL GROUP BY COLUMN_1;
```